# Issue with getting buttons side by side in table row

Tags: html, css, button

I have trying to get the two key buttons side by side from each other, instead the second but jumps to the next line.

Been stuck with this for a few days now and i have tried using display: display-inline and float: right, but have been unsuccessful. 
Can someone please help me find the solution to this problem. I have used a link to jfiddle which includes my HTML and CSS.

[enter link description here][1]

```
<th colspan="4">Header</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Twinkle STARS


                    <button class="key-button">#### ####</button> 
                    <button class="key-button2">#### ####</button> 


                </td> 

  [1]: ht
```

tps://jsfiddle.net/1nzr3yjf/

Comment: is `td:first-child{white-space:nowrap}`an option ? http://jsfiddle.net/ptb9vd58/

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the width of your buttons. Try  `width: 100px;` for `.key-button, .key-button2`